# Auto-Scrolling TextArea in QML Sailfish / Silica

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, sailfish-os

**Update:** Possible solution at the bottom.

I am learning App development for Sailfish with very little prior experience in Qt/QML but some experience in other Toolkits (GTK, Tk, Motif, Xaw).

I am currently writing a dumb chat client (no protocoll, just send text over network.)  I have the Talk/Chat page defined in QML as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Sailfish.Silica 1.0

Page {
    id: talkPage

    PageHeader {
        id: header

        title: qsTr("Talk")

        width: parent.width
        anchors.top: parent.top
    }

    TextField {
        id: message

        placeholderText: qsTr("Type your Message...")

        width: parent.width
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        EnterKey.onClicked: {
            log.text += "\n> " + text;
            text = "";
        }
    }

    TextArea {
        id: log

        readOnly: true
        wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap

        width: parent.width
        anchors.top: header.bottom
        anchors.bottom: message.top

        text: qsTr("Talk log")
    }
}
```

You can now enter text in the `message` TextField and hit enter to add it to the `log` TextArea.

**Question:** How to I make the TextArea auto-scroll to the bottom each time a message is added to it.

Note that if I understand correctly, this is using Sailfish.Silica TextField, and this is different from standard (QtQuick.Components ?)  So I cannot use `log.append("\n> " + text);` from QtQuick.Controls (which isn't available on Sailfish.)

A sollution in using C++ rather than Javascript/QML is fine to, since I'll need it to handle Networking anyway.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

**Bonus Question:**  I tried arranging `header`, `message` and `log` in a `Column` previously, but didn't know how to make `header` and `message` keep their default height but make `log` expand to fill the screen.  In GTK there is an expand property for this.  Any hints?

**Possible Solution:**  Put the TextArea inside a SilicaFlickable.  For some reason TextArea is already scrollable without this extra step, but this way one can use `scrollToBottom()` and force the desired behavior.  As a bonus, in this way we can add a nice scrollbar.

Comment: I'll just delete the answer. Apparently the SailfishOS has decided to be special.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!  Indeed it seems that Sailfish uses Silica and leaves out many relevant parts of QtQuick such as QtQuick.Layouts and QtQuick.Controls.  Then they define their own TextArea etc types which differ from the "standard" ones.  Probably makes it really hard / annoying to port existing Qt apps to Sailfish.